# Session management in Java Web App

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets

I am creating an E shopping project in Java and I'm stucked due to session in my project. I had a user login page, when user logged in, it will validate through the Servlet and it creates a new session, then it will go to `productslist.jsp`

Now my problem is, if the user copy the url of `productslist.jsp` and re-entered it in the address bar, he can directly go to the `productslist.jsp` page, what can I do to restrict the user to login before browsing to pages?

Comment: If you are using plain servlets (which I don't recommend) you can always write own security filter. In that filter you will check if user is logged in (e.g. some parameter in session added after login). If not - filter will reject request and you can redirect user to login page. I said that I don't recommend plain servlets - look at good frameworks which do this for you and you can then write your business logic only (such as Spring Framework).

Comment: ok,thank you @ArekWoźniak..i got an idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to validate session in all your pages to avoid un-authorized access or direct access.

```
<%  request.getSession();
    String ses=(String) session.getAttribute("usr");
    if (session != null && !session.isNew()) {

    } else if(!session.equals(ses))
            {
        response.sendRedirect("loginPage.jsp");
    }
%>
```

But it is not recommended to do so as it creates code duplication in all pages ,

1. You can intercept your requests to the servlet
2. Another thing you can do is [`ServletFilters`](http://www.journaldev.com/1933/java-servlet-filter-example-tutorial)

To prevent direct access to the `.jsp` pages, you can put them under **WEB-INF** which needs to intercept the requests from servlet

Comment: Filter would be a better option, otherwise there will be duplicate code in all pages

Comment: @SanKrish,do i need to include page directive  <%@page session="false"%>..if i do,during runtime it shows error

Comment: No if you include the ` <%@page session="false"%>` in your page , then you cant make use of sessions in that particular page